# ARI JS client mute error "Channel not in Stasis application"

Tags: express, asterisk

Am currently developing a mute function for asterisk which I can run from my web front end using asterisk ARI.

But every time I try to run/call the mute function it gives me the following error:

```
Error: {
  "message": "Channel not in Stasis application"
}
```

But it is, as far as am aware am passing the channel data directly to this function but to no avail.

Any one any suggestions or used to working with the ARI JS client?

**Client Side**

When mute button is clicked emit the data found in td to the server side.

```
   $(document).on('click', '.mute', function () {
        var mute = $(this).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text();
        socket.emit('muting', mute);
        if ($(this).hasClass('mute')) {
            $(this).removeClass('mute').addClass('unmute').find('span').text('Unmute');
        } else {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
```

**Server Side**

Store the data received from client side into a var and then call the stasis function.

```
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    updateSip();
    socket.on('muting', function (data) {
        mute(data);
        console.log("Reached listener for muting")
    });
});
```

**Stasis function**

Mute the channel which you have just passed from client to server side using ARI client commands, user will be muted and will show in stasis application.

```
function mute(mutval) {
    console.log("Muting:" + mutval);
    client.channels.mute
    ({
        channelId : mutval
    },
        function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });

}
```

The channel is in the application and being passed to the mute function, so am not sure as to way its not working currently.

I have also tried running it via socket.io and without it and the outcome is the same, I have other functions and they all work just fine, its just the mute function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it would not run because it needed channel ID and not channel name, but functions would run with channel name.

It is inconsistency with the Asterisk ARI as it should work with channel name and not just channel ID like other functions did such as hangup and originate functions.

Comment: It isn't an inconsistency within ARI - the operations require a channel ID in the path, not a name. Generally, that's because in practice, IDs are a better handle to a channel for two reasons: (1) names can be re-used in obscure cases; (2) IDs can be provided by the app, while names are always auto-generated.

I agree it is inconsistent with historic Asterisk, but that sometimes happens with newer APIs/features.